# Para que serve e como usar include_path no php

Tags: php

Tenho pego muitos scripts usando include_path, o problema é que a explicação do php.net acho um pouco confusa, não estou conseguindo entender como funciona e para que serve, help me please

Answer (score 2):

Em termos simples permite que ao utilizar uma dessas funções: require, include, fopen(), file(), readfile() e file_get_contents(), não será necessário informar o caminho completo, uma vez que informado o nome do arquivo, o php vai buscar nas pastas existentes dentro do include_path.

**A explicação da documentação está abaixo:**

"Especifica a lista de diretórios onde as funções require, include, fopen(), file(), readfile() e file_get_contents() procuração por arquivos. O formato é igual a variável de ambiente PATH: uma lista de diretórios separadas por virgula nos Unix e ponto e virgula no Windows.

O PHP considera cara item no include_path separadamente quando procurando por arquivos a incluir. Ele checará o primeiro caminho, e se não encontrar aqui, procurará no próximo e assim por diante, até que encontra o arquivo ou retorna um warning ou error. Você pode modificar o include_path durante a execução utilizando set_include_path()."

[Referência](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.include-path)